CSS - "object-fit: cover" not working in html email body
I would like to ask you for a help with html email body. I have issue with parameter "object-fit: cover;" which actually works greate when displayed on web, but not working when used in html email body.
EmailProvider: New Outlook in WIN PC
Mobile: Outlook too
Here is example code:


body {
  background-color: ;
  font-family: roboto;
}

.PanelPicture {
  background-color: #87878732;
  height: 90px;
  max-width: 500px;
  text-align: ;
  border-radius: 9px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #878787FF;
  border-width: 2px;
  padding-top: ;
  padding-right: ;
  padding-left: ;
  padding-bottom: ;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.PanelBackground {
  background-color: #2A2A2ACC;
  max-width: 500px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #878787FF;
  border-width: 2px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.Scena1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: px;
  display: ;
  opacity: 1;
  object-fit: cover;
  margin-left: ;
  margin-top: ;
  margin-bottom: ;
  margin-right: ;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border-style: ;
  border-color: ;
  border-width: 0px;
}
<center>
  <div class="PanelBackground">
    <div class="PanelPicture">
      <img src="paris.jpg" alt="Paris" , class="Scena1">
    </div>
  </div>
</center>



To test you can change and "paris.jpg" for any picture you have , even you can test it here on w3schools - just switch codes in there and keep picture (picture is from that pages)
Issue:
When I receive this on my email box picture is not fit within ".PanelPicture" instead of it is overlaying it.
I found this pages from Can I Email - css object fit which tells me that my email xo should support this feature.
I expect code revision to help me with fitting the picture in the panel for email html body too.

Outlook supports an extremely limited (aka, outdated) subset of CSS. The site you linked to suggests that object-fit is not supported in any version of Windows Outlook.

The new Outlook uses a different rendering engine and is actually much closer to Outlook.com. However, this particular client has not been tested on caniemail, so it's hard to say whether it should work or not.

Emails are a different beast than web.
I did the standard things: inlined code, used tables instead of divs, and tidied up things like 8 character HEX colours to 6, and it all worked as expected (old Windows Outlook not supported - but could use conditional comments; Yahoo/AOL not supported - as with OL, it shows the whole image)
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html lang="en" xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
   <!-- START HEAD v5-->
  <head></head>
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <!--[if !mso]><!-->
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <!--<![endif]-->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
      <title></title>
</head>
 <!-- END HEAD -->
<body>
<center style="font-family: roboto;">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation">
      <tr>
          <td style="background-color: #2A2A2A;  max-width: 300px;  text-align: center;  border-radius: 8px;  border-style: solid;  border-color: #878787;  border-width: 2px;  margin-top: 30px;  margin-right: 20px;  margin-left: 20px;  margin-bottom: 30px;padding:5px;">
              <center>
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation"  align="center">
                    <tr>
                        <td width="300"  style="background-color: #878787;  height: 90px;  max-width: 300px;  border-radius: 9px;  border-style: solid;  border-color: #878787;  border-width: 2px;  margin-top: 5px;  margin-right: 10px;  margin-left: 10px;  margin-bottom: 5px;">
                  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/400/300" alt="Paris" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; object-fit: cover; border-radius: 8px;">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
              </center>
          </td>
        </tr>
  </table>
</center>
</body>

